# How to put a video or Img Seq over a video?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to put either a MP4 video, or an Image Seq over a video. But unfortunately the video shows with a black background although I did change the Render/Film/Alpha setting from Sky to Transparent. And the Image Seq shows in bright pink.

Compositing Noodle
[image: Compositing Noodle]

Image Seq Noodle

[image: Image Seq Noodle]

What could I be missing?

Comment: Pink color means that Image file couldn't be loaded

Comment: The VSE makes this much easier. Do you need to use the Compositor?